# how to use vuex-persistentstate along with existing store(vuex) setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-storefront

I am trying to setup usercredentials plus token in localstorage when ever a usersignin. The user have a profile picture whenever he update his profile picture. The existing profile image(localstorage) is shown to the user unless he relaod the page. only then the image is shown to him. I have tried using both vuex and localstorage.Vuex is not persistent and computed properties don't get the updated value until the page is reloaded again. I found a plugin name vuex-persistentstorage but i can't find a way to use it along my existing store. Any solution or example in how to use my store with persistent storage will be really helpful. Here is what i am trying to get. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: I know that my answer may be out of scope, but at least for tokens or information of that nature, it is greatly recommended to store it in a HttpOnly cookie, localStorate is accessible by any script your page, HttpOnly cookie is sent on every request and its not accessible by your code.

https://logrocket.com/blog/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

Comment: thank you i will surely use it.

Comment: I have used [https://alligator.io/vuejs/vuex-persist-state/] along with demo [https://codesandbox.io/s/80k4m2598?autoresize=1]                                                     This solved the problem of computed properties not reacting to changes in local storage.